# Unable to import 'MinMaxScaler' from sklearn.preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I tried all possible ways and checked everywhere, but I couldn't find the ideal solution.

- Uninstalled sklearn, scikit-learn
- Installed sklearn 0.23
- Upgraded sklearn

but I still didn't succeed.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MinMaxScalar' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (C:\Users\MY PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Um.. Your error says MinMaxScal**a**r, whereas the class you want has **e** in it?

Answer (score 3):

You should change the letter `A` to an `E`, so `MinMaxScalar` changes to `MinMaxScaler`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last letter `a` to `e` in class name

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```